# the XML code isn't readable anymore

Tags: php, xml

my Xml code is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <data>
   <result>
    <index-1>
    <name>paris</name>
    <latitude>41.615564</latitude>
    <longitude>98.28819</longitude>
    <hotels>401</hotels>
    <onlineHotels>76</onlineHotels>
    </index>
    <index-2>
    <name>london</name>
    <latitude>74.368358</latitude>
    <longitude>96.722347</longitude>
    <hotels>124</hotels>
    <onlineHotels>42</onlineHotels>
    </index>
    </result>

    </data>
 </xml>
```

in php I want to print all  name data but it does not work properly

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("hc.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $index) {
echo $index->name . ", ";
echo "<br>";
} 
?>
```

Important note
 xml file
Should not change.

Comment: In what way does it not work properly? I'm guessing it doesn't fill your monitor with farting donkey gifs ... but that still leaves an awful lot of different ways for it to be *wrong*.

Comment: Maybe you see it,  and maybe ...:)

Comment: Your xml definition would more usually be like -`<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

Comment: @eliteandot Why did you changed your question in a way that the XML code isn't readable anymore?

Comment: @eliteandot Where did you get that invalid XML file from? Can you ask the author to give you a valid XML file?

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is not valid.

You have an element called "index-1" which is terminated with "/index". This will break as the file is being read. You say that the XML file must not change but it will never work without the change.

> The element type "index-1" must be terminated by the matching end-tag.

Comment: But this xml file works right now,I checked the file and  code  with Help web service  in the host  and  "connectionMode is curl"

Comment: Would probably make more sense if the opening `<index-*>` tags were just called `<index>` but had an `id` attribute (though that attribute would have to start with an alpha character of course or, again, the XML would be invalid).